# Fetching characters with node-fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, parsing, node-fetch

I am writing a browser application in ReactJS that should manipulate and display data from robot [Wifibot Lab](https://wifibot.com/). It sends me 21 chars from which every one of them stands for the status of different device on the robot. While fetching the data from the robot directly into the web app I've encountered a problem with CORS, it was blocking multiple requests. So I was trying to bypass this problem with CORS proxy server, that would serve as an mediator between bot and my application but there I got stuck.

The problem appeared in the `fetch()` function. In frontend (ReactJS) I can fetch the data easily with this block of code:

```
 async function customFetch(){
            var response = await fetch("http://192.168.0.1:15020");
            const reader = response.body.getReader();
            let temp = await reader.read();
            console.log("[got response]: "+temp)
        }
```

But when I passed this block of code to handle "the same" operation in my proxy server (Node.js) it always gives me this type of error:

```
FetchError: request to http://192.168.1.106:15020/ failed, reason: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
    at ClientRequest.
```

In Node.js I am using `node-fetch` library. It says 'Parse Error'... but frontend parses it seamlessly.

So my question is what am I doing wrong? Is there any difference between fetch in ReactJS and node-fetch? How should I fetch this type of data properly in Node.js?

Comment: Which side throws this error? the client or your proxy? Seems like the service at 192.168.1.106:15020 returns a malformed http response ...

Comment: The proxy throws the error

Comment: I don't know that product, but looking at its docs, it does only provide a *raw TCP* connection and not a http connection. Thus, you cannot communicate with an HTTP client, but you need raw TCP sockets ...